# How to 'count' only when header matches value?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Form that collects a bunch of data from dropdown questions on a Sheet with each question going to one column (as normal). On separate sheets, I want to be able to count how many times each option is selected.
Here is an example of what the response sheet might look like. A, B, and C are all questions.

[image: Input Sample]

I would then have separate sheets for 'Person?', 'Place?', and 'Thing?'. The 'Person?' sheet would look something like this:

[image: Person sheet]

I want to be able to add in the count of each time the option appears for *that question*. In the example, notice that 'Napoleon" is in both Col A and Col C. If I just count the number of times 'Napoleon' appears, I will get '2' even though he only appears once in the "Person?" responses.

I originally used a QUERY function like `=QUERY('Input Data'!1:1000, "select count(A) where A contains '"&$A2&"'",0)`. BUT, I need it to be dynamic. So the "Person?" question may not always be Col A. I want the Query (or whatever formula) to search the headers and only return the count of that option for that question even if the column location changes.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I figured it out! In case someone else is curious, I used this formula:

```
=QUERY({'Input Data'!A1:L}, "SELECT COUNT(Col"&MATCH("Person?", 'Input Data'!1:1,0)&") WHERE Col"&MATCH("Person?", 'Input Data'!1:1,0)&" CONTAINS '"&$A2&"' label COUNT(Col"&MATCH("Person?", 'Input Data'!1:1,0)&") ''",0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Lee, I sent you a PM about your most recent post, but in the process, I came across this one. There is no need for multiple formulas or manual entry references. One formula can produce the entire report with headers, listing and counts:

`=IFERROR(QUERY(FILTER(FILTER(A:L,A:A<>""),A1:L1="Person?"),"Select Col1, COUNT(Col1) GROUP BY Col1 ORDER BY Col1 LABEL COUNT(Col1) 'Count'",1),"No Matches")`

Just fill in the header your looking for between the quotes where `Person?` is now.

The double `FILTER`s mean "Start with only rows where Col A is not null and Row 1 reads 'Person?'"

Then `QUERY` simply returns the unique names in the left column and their counts in the right column. Because the `QUERY` had a final parameter of `1`, any existing header will be kept (in this case, the one you were searching for); and the created column will receive a header (i.e., `LABEL`) of `Count`.

`IFERROR` will give a friendly error message if no matches are found (in which case check that what you entered for the search in the formula exactly matches a column header in the range).